# Having problem with React js project while deploying project

Tags: reactjs

I m new to react, having some problems with build and uploading project.

If I upload with out adding react-router-dom it works fine, but when i upload files from build folder after importing react-router-dom, blank page appears
but there are not any errors in console. Files and codes are visible from the source tab from Developer tools.

Note: With out react-router-dom all the html renders in browser. Also I have added /folder-name/static....(for chunks and manifest)

This is the code to import react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

No any error messages in console.

Answer (score 0):

Install both react-router and react-router-dom.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer on github page, was not aware of basename for BrowserRouter.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/BrowserRouter.md